# Random HTTPs redirections at admin area in shared hosting

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, https, shared-hosting

While editing or writing a new post, sometimes I get redirected to the following address:
https://www.examplesite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://www.examplesite.com/wp-admin/edit.php&reauth=1

Even though i wasn't navigating using https. We don't have an SSL certificate for our domain, so we get the following warning message: "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate."

I have around 30 wordpress websites hosted on Hostinger, and all of them gives this issue.

Any idea what causes it?
I've seen a temporary solution might be adding

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

To wp-config.php, but I'm looking for a permanent solution, and the root of the problem...

Comment: If you go to Settings -> General in your WordPress admin, what is listed as the WordPress Address and Site Address?

Comment: They are both http://, it seems it might be a session bug, I've seen other people with shared grid hosting having the same issue (ex: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/backend-http-to-https-redirection?replies=10)

Comment: I'm not sure what shared grid hosting is, but maybe you need to talk to your host then...